# Movie about an old scientist creating a beautiful robot/cyborg

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is going to be very vague as I was around 8 when I watched it. The movie is from the '70s or '80s.

An older, white-haired scientist (he was short in stature) created a robot or cyborg. She was a beautiful blonde female, and taller than him. As soon as she wakes up or whatever, he gives her a lab coat to cover up.

There is a part where she is changing behind a curtain, the old scientist pretends to be dusting and says, “*doing nothing…looking at something*” while taking a peek.

Comment: Live action or animated?

Comment: This could be ANDROID (1982). Look at these photos - white-haired scientist and blonde android female: https://new.cineplex.com/Movie/android/Photos